# repeatWhen() does not complete

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I'm running into a problem with getting `repeatWhen()` to work with a `Completable`. The below code block is working. The subscribed `Action` ends up running after the repeats.

```
completable
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.trampoline()) //for debug purposes; have also omitted completely
.repeat(2)
.observeOn(Schedulers.trampoline()) //for debug purposes; have also omitted completely
.subscribe(new Action() {
    @Override
    public void run() throws Exception {
        //runs
    }
}
```

However, when I try the following

```
completable
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.trampoline()) //for debug purposes; have also omitted completely
.repeatWhen(new MyRetry(2))
.observeOn(Schedulers.trampoline()) //for debug purposes; have also omitted completely
.subscribe(new Action() {
    @Override
    public void run() throws Exception {
        //doesn't run
    }
}
```

With `MyRetry` being defined as follows:

```
class MyRetry implements Function<Flowable<Object>, Publisher<?>> {

    private final int maxRetryCount;
    private int retryCount;

    /**
     * @param maxRetryCount The number of times to repeat
     */
    public MyRetry(final int maxRetryCount) {
        this.maxRetryCount = maxRetryCount;
        retryCount = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Publisher<?> apply(final Flowable<Object> objectFlowable) throws Exception {
        return objectFlowable.flatMap(new Function<Object, Publisher<?>>() {
            @Override
            public Publisher<?> apply(final Object o) throws Exception {
                if (retryCount < maxRetryCount) {
                    retryCount++;
                    return Flowable.just(o);
                } else {
                    return Flowable.empty();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The subscribed `Action` never runs after finished repeating, but the original subscription to the `Completable` is repeated twice. This leads me to believe that I'm probably not correct in returning `Flowable.empty()`, but I cannot find information on the subject and I'm fairly new to RxJava. I also have infrastructure limitations leaving me still stuck on Java 7 in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial subscriber would receive `onCompleted()` event if you change `flatMap()` to `takeUntil()` within your `MyRetry` class:

```
@Override
public Publisher<?> apply(final Flowable<Object> objectFlowable) throws Exception {
    return objectFlowable.takeWhile(o -> retryCount++ < maxRetryCount);
}
```

<sup>This issue has been discussed in [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/2889#issuecomment-109416415)
 thread.</sup>

Comment: Can you explain why this is working in a little more detail? I thought all the notification handler was doing was applying a yes/no through turning an onNext() vs onComplete(). The thread you linked has someone pose the question I just asked, but with no response.